# Pandas: fastest way to the DF by date

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have an efficiency question for you.  I wrote some code to analyze a report that holds over 70k records and over 400+ unique organizations to allow my supervisor to enter in year/month/date they are interested in and have it pop out the information.

The beginning of my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
main_data = pd.read_excel("UpdatedData.xlsx", encoding= 'utf8')

#column names from DF
epi_expose = "EpitheliumExposureSeverity"
sloughing = "EpitheliumSloughingPercentageSurface"
organization = "OrgName"
region = "Region"
date = "DeathOn"

#list storage of definitions
sl_list = ["",'None','Mild','Mild to Moderate']
epi_list= ['Moderate','Moderate to Severe','Severe']

#Create DF with four columns
df = main_data[[region, organization, epi_expose, sloughing, date]]

#filter it down to months
starting_date = datetime.date(2017,2,1)
ending_date = datetime.date(2017,2,28)

df = df[(df[date] > starting_date) & (df[date] < ending_date)]
```

I am then performing conditional filtering below to get counts by region and organization.  It works, but is slow.  Is there a more efficient way to query my DF and set up a DF that ONLY has the dates that it is supposed to sit between?  Or is this the most efficient way without altering how the Database I am using is set up?

I can provide more of my code but if I filter it out by month before exporting to excel, the code runs in a matter of seconds so I am not concerned about the speed of it besides getting the correct date fields.

Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, the first line after the imports where you read in the big excel file is probably what is slow, not the filtering by dates

Comment: @kev8484 would it be best to convert to csv for speed?

Comment: Yeah that's what I would try.  In my experience, it's noticeably quicker to read in a csv file

Comment: @kev8484 I will give that a shot then as right now the process is taking upwards of 3-5 minutes to run. Not detrimental just slower then I would like.  Thank you!

Comment: @kev8484 hopefully this will be a easy question too. Comparing dtype datetime64[ns] to my datetime date is causing some extra records to fall through, is there a better datetime to use?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and provide some more context for this issue